# Identify bad meter readings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a series of meter readings sent in by field techs that tend to have finger checks & provide absolutely bizarre readings.  Do you have any idea how I can identify the "Bad" meter readings using Excel?

```
Meter #    Meter Reading   Reading Date   Reading good or bad?
35397220      108,825       02/05/2015      Good
35397220      116,583       02/10/2015      Good
35397220      156,354       02/13/2015      Good
35397220      145,000       02/24/2015      Bad
35397220      145,000       02/27/2015      Bad
35397220      217,705       03/02/2015      Good
35397220      221,014       03/03/2015      Good
35397220    2,232,372       03/04/2015      Bad
35397220      259,394       03/10/2015      Good
35397220      288,093       03/11/2015      Good
35397220      332,660       03/18/2015      Good
35397220    2,334,216       03/19/2015      Bad
```

Comment: What do you mean by "identify" the bad readings?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. On the surface this looks like Column D already identifies them. But I don't think that is what you are asking or you would have used conditional formatting to highlight the rows with "Bad" in column D. Please read **[ask]**, then update your question to include clarification and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: the question is very badly asked, but judging by the set the data is supposed to be bad if either a) they are a round number at more than 2 digits or b) if they're about ten time the size of the mean of the sample. You could set this as a Excel list and use a formula like if(OR(mod(b1;100)>0,b1>avg(Meter Reading)*10),"Bad","Good")

Answer (score 1):

One possible Example based on Assumptions

1. It is treated as ‘Bad’ if there’s very large difference (positive) from previous reading OR if the reading is less than previous on incremental time scale.
2. Data is sorted on Date Column in ascending order
3. You have to treat the reading you wish to start with as ‘Good’ as a reference point and derive rest of the calculations based on that.
4. In this answer increase of up to 99,999 from previous reading is acceptable. This value can be adjusted in the formula as per required

[image]

Explanation

Starting Column E3 it checks for increase in value OR not too much increase in value against ‘Previous Good’ Column F and marks ‘Good’ or ‘Bad’. 
Simultaneously based on this status the Column F takes this current Good value as ‘Previous Good’ for next row or retains ’Last Good’. This way the last latest 'Previous Good' is available in F for next derivation in Column E.

Full picture is clear only when both Columns E & F hold the respective formula till end of the table. Hope my assumptions are right and this helps!

Op may like to provide further clarity how the ‘Good’ & ‘Bad’ is being identified and based on that solutions may vary!

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'm good. I like the formula that checks a value against the average readings. So anything less than the prior reading or greater than the average of the readings would be considered as a bad reading.